# HTML Editor with Download Option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to add a download feature to my JS that will create a file using the programming that a user might enter in, lets say, a `<textarea>`. Are there any features in JS that would work similar to this? (**HTML Format!!**)

```
var x = document.write("<p>Hi!</p>");
window.replace(x);
```

And then:

```
<button onclick="open()">Save</button>
<script>
  var hi = document.write("<p>hi</p>;");
  open() {
    window.open(hi)
  }
</script>
```

After they opened the variable on the new page, the user could use ctrl + s to save the page displayed. Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<textarea id="text-val" rows="4" style="height: 80%;width: 90%;"></textarea><br/><br/>
<input type="button" id="dwn-btn" value="Save" />
<script>
    function download(filename, text) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);

        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }

    document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

        var text = document.getElementById("text-val").value;
        var filename = "example.html";

        download(filename, text);
    }, false);
</script>
```

I hope this is what you are expecting

Comment: for that you should pass them as query parameter like blah.com?text=hello and get them in the next page

Comment: if it works mark this as right answer and up vote it as per

Comment: That is a great idea. I understand, and it would work, but I just now realized that the code would save as the code, and not save the var that I wanted to. Please look at my updated question for more on what I was thinking.

Comment: @KwilverBear your question is answered , if it works please mark this as right answer and up vote it as per

Comment: ask for new question if you need answers for new one......Please check the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Create new [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) from your html script with `application/octet-stream` mime type. Then use `URL.createOjectURL` api to generate download link. And navigate to that link. In this example code I navigated using creating temporary link (`<a>`) element.

```js
function download() {
  var blobPart = ['<h1>Test</h1>'];
  var blob = new Blob(blobPart, {
    type: "application/octet-stream"
  });
  var urlObj = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');

  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.href = urlObj;
  a.download = 'filename.html';
  a.click();
  a.remove();
}

document.getElementById('download-btn').addEventListener('click', download);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="download-btn">Download</a>
```